# Add new rows to a shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile, fields-attributes, table

I'm using QGIS. When I enable editing of a shapefile's table attributes and select, 'open attribute table,' is it possible to add new rows to the shapefile's table attributes?

The problem I'm trying to solve is that some of my polygons were not imported with my shapefile. I need to add them.

Comment: Every row in a shapefile's attribute table is a feature (point, line, or polygon). To create a new row, you need to create a new feature.

Comment: I'm using QGIS.

Comment: I would recommend editing your question to update it with those additional details so that people thinking about answering just have to read the question rather than many comments as well.

Comment: Is it possible to join the layer with another layer. it depends on how you added your data and from what source, as if it was an original shapefile then they will all be there.  however if it is a dxf that has been converted into a shapefile, it is possible that some of your polygons are incomplete and get "lost".

Answer (score 1):

Dan C's comment is correct, you cannot just add rows, all rows are associated with features on the map (lines, points, or polygons). When a new feature is added a new row will appear for it.

For a tutorial on how to add these see: https://github.com/mtop/speciesgeocoder/wiki/Tutorial-for-creating-polygons-in-QGIS

Answer (score -1):

First, you need to make your layer editable. Then, you need to open your attribute table. You have an option to add a new row (the black circle in the image).[image]
You could also use a plugin called « table manager ». It works quite well. http://www.portailsig.org/content/plugin-qgis-table-manager

Comment: The icon highlighted by Laurent in answer above is add column icon. its not for adding a row.